# What new does geometric or deformation quantization give to physics?

Tags: mathematical-physics, quantization, deformation-quantization

What new does [geometric quantization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_quantization) or deformation quantization give to physics?
For example: prediction of new physical phenomena or just better tool for quantization.
What can these schemes do in comparison with old approaches (canonical,..etc)? 
From physical point of view!
I only saw description of mathematical application.

Comment: This question seems very broad, since an exhaustive description and perceived advantages of one quantization procedure over others is necessarily almost of book-length.

Comment: Not description advantages, only physical profit :)

Comment: *a better tool for quantization* is necessarily an opinion-based question, which is usually considered off-topic.

Comment: allows for general configuration and phase spaces?

Comment: Mathematically speaking, the main advantage of deformation quantisation is that you do not need to introduce the ad-hoc concept of Hilbert space to develop a quantum mechanics opposed to the classical one. Instead, everything stays in the Poisson/symplectic manifold and you construct an algebra which is non-commutative using differential tools. As far as I know, it's the only mathematically viable way of quantisation at the present time, all the other scheme prove to be really hard, if not impossible to quantise. I lack a good reference on that, sorry I'm from a physics side.

Comment: My understanding is that it's not a well studied method in physics, especially not in field theory, and it's rather tedious mathematically speaking. But it has some advantages. Physical topics which use deformation quantisation (called in different context gradient expansion, or mixed-Fourier transformed, or quasi-classic expansion) are i) transport phenomena in condensed matter and ii) quasi-classical probability distribution in quantum optics . Sloppy speaking, you can usually do at the quasi-classic level exactly what you can do in path-integral approach, but in a much simpler way.