# References on deformation quantization

Tags: mathematical-physics, resource-recommendations, quantization, deformation-quantization

I'm looking for books or introductory review papers or lecture notes on the topic of deformation quantization. (And preferably, geometric quantization as well.) I'm mainly interested in the mathematics. I know that this involves alot of interesting topics of math but I also would like to know how mathematical quantization is useful in physics.

Comment: [Woodhouse (1992)](http://www.amazon.com/Geometric-Quantization-Oxford-Mathematical-Monographs/dp/0198502702). See also [other amazon books](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=deformation+quantization). Did you at least try to look around a bit before asking?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/197352/2451

Comment: Yes , I did. Most of these books on amazon are quite expensive , no customer reviews and I'm not sure what the intended audience of each of these books are.

Comment: Qmechanic , The other question is closed and has no answers , I wonder how could that be useful ?

Comment: I do not know much about the mathematical aspects of deformation quantisation, but an introduction containing some historical references is http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9809056 See also http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/deformation+quantization on nLab and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space_formulation on wikipedia. Especially, check the link from the Wiki page, for instance about the Kontsevich's formula : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kontsevich_quantization_formula and all references therein. Good luck to you.

Comment: Might well try [this](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/a.pdf) .